# Error while launching emulator

Tags: android

I have installed android sdk in `C:\Android\andoird-sdk-windows`.I have created one sample application..While launching the emulator,
it is giving error as:

```
Invalid command-line parameter: New.
Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
please use -help for more information
```

There is no white space in the folder structure where I have installed android sdk..I am new to Android development..Please help me.

Thanks in advance,

Nagendra Shasthri S

Comment: Did you forget to create a virtual device?

Comment: Provide us more info: how are you launching the emulator, are you using Eclipse?

Comment: @Pulkit..I have created virtual device..@Primoz..Ya I am using eclipse..I created just hello world application..After building it,I gave run as android application..Then I am getting this error message.

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a space in the name of the virtual device? Try to create a new one in the AVD manager, without spaces in the name.

Comment: There is no space in the name of virtual device..I have given the name as KTWo..Shall I re-install android sdk,ADt once more more and try it again?

Comment: Well, you could try. And double-check that the installation that is being used actually is one without spaces in the path, so you aren't accidentally using an old one, for example installed under C:\Program Files.